# Pass function which sets child state as prop for this.props.children

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass `handleClose` as prop for `this.props.children`. This function must access to child state. I have a problem with `{handleClose: this.handleClose}` because I don't understand how to pass parameter `child` here.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    handleClose(child) {
        if (child.state.redirect) {
            browserHistory.push(url);
        } else {
            child.setState({showError: false, errorText: ''});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, 
                {handleClose: this.handleClose}, this);
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function that runs a function with the parameter

**Example**

```
React.cloneElement(child, {handleClose: function () { this.handleClose(child); }.bind(this)}, this);

// OR

React.cloneElement(child, {handleClose: () => this.handleClose(child)}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks! Second variant helped me.

Comment: If this answered your question make to sure to mark this as the right answer so people know that it worked and that the question is solved